# Localization problems in WSP template

Tags: 2013, solution-package

I configure a SharePoint 2013 site using the web interface. I save the site as a template, a WSP package. I then utilize this template on new, clean, team sites.

It works great almost all the times.

However, a few times, I get an error message about corrupt xml in the package. The error message tells me that the attribute $Resources:core,True_Unless_Jpn; isn’t valid, it should be a simple true or false. The localized string isn’t being managed correctly.

I can’t see any signs of any other localization problems or other problems in general.

The error remain within the same web application until I do one or sometimes several IISResets or recycles of the application pool. After this everything may work great for a few days or months until the error appear once again.

The application pools are recycled automatically every night and my best guess is that something goes wrong from time to time, causing problems to the localization.

All ideas are appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Was the language pack installed correctly? Are there any errors in ULS logs?

Comment: Please let me know if you received a solution - I am having the exact same problem you are describing.

Comment: We have installed one additional language pack and I haven’t seen any other problems indicating a problem with it. No other problem or log entry indicate any problems. The sites we were trying to provision while getting this problem were English sites.
The only error I have found in the ULS logs is the error message described in my original post. 
Unfortunately no additional clues or solution yet. We haven’t seen the problem in a while but if it re surface we will probably create a Microsoft case and try and see if they can help us get a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: Have you gotten the same error again? Since now I'm having the same problem..

Comment: No, not recently. Please share if you will find anything interesting.

Comment: I am also getting the same error when I upload a template to the solutions section of a newly created site collection.  We don't have any extra language packs installed.

Comment: Have you ever enabled / dsiabled the publishing features on the orginal site? I noticed strange behavior with "Save site as template" after publishing features were enabled. Disabling publishing features does not help. You have to create the site from scratch.

Comment: Since it works after an IIReset I would think a feature is loading a newer/incorrect version of the "core resource" file into the memory of your IIS/application pool. Any other custom solutions installed on the server?

Comment: I had a similar problem but not directly related. From time to time our left navigation panel would not show any items. The problem was there until we ran IISRESET. After many attempts we localized a problem to custom web part which was actually updating managed navigation. So whenever any user browsed the page containing this webpart, left navigation panel would break for everyone. My advice is look for the page visits in ULS/IIS logs that were visited just before problem starts to appear.

Answer (score 1):

Going further in the logs and in the template file, i noticed that the columns using this $Resources:core,True_Unless_Jpn; are located in the following content types:

```
<ContentType ID="0x0116" Name="East Asia Contact"

<FieldRef ID="{fdc8216d-dabf-441d-8ac0-f6c626fbdc24}" Name="LastNamePhonetic" Required="FALSE" Hidden="$Resources:core,True_Unless_Jpn" />
<FieldRef ID="{ea8f7ca9-2a0e-4a89-b8bf-c51a6af62c73}" Name="FirstNamePhonetic" Hidden="$Resources:core,True_Unless_Jpn" />
<FieldRef ID="{034aae88-6e9a-4e41-bc8a-09b6c15fcdf4}" Name="CompanyPhonetic" Hidden="$Resources:core,True_Unless_Jpn" />
```

and

```
<ContentType ID="0x0106" Name="Contact"

<FieldRef ID="{fdc8216d-dabf-441d-8ac0-f6c626fbdc24}" Name="LastNamePhonetic" Required="FALSE" Hidden="$Resources:core,True_Unless_Jpn" />
<FieldRef ID="{ea8f7ca9-2a0e-4a89-b8bf-c51a6af62c73}" Name="FirstNamePhonetic" Hidden="$Resources:core,True_Unless_Jpn" />
<FieldRef ID="{034aae88-6e9a-4e41-bc8a-09b6c15fcdf4}" Name="CompanyPhonetic" Hidden="$Resources:core,True_Unless_Jpn" />
```

After removing those columns from those content types i haven't experienced problems so far

Comment: This section is for answers only. Please edit your original post to add more information.

Answer (score 0):

Verify your core resource file at following location:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\Resources

See if you can find entry for "True_Unless_Jpn". If not, create one and save.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem when adding solutions to a newly created site collection.

Adding a sleep of 30 seconds between the site creation and the installation of solutions resolved the issue.

For more details see my blog post:

https://veenstra.me.uk/2018/10/01/sharepoint-long-running-powershell-migration-scripts-fail-on-install-spusersolution/